# Insert into a temp table after a SELECT clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that generates a temp table wiht like 40 columns and then returns the data.

In a very simplified format the data I need comes out like this:

```
DESCR      CHG   LATEFEE    TOTAL
=================================
Assessment  1       5         6
Spec        3       2         5
Res         3       0         3
```

What I'm looking for is a way to add a new record below that contains the total of all the `LATEFEE`, `CHG`, and `TOTAL` values.

```
DESCR      CHG   LATEFEE    TOTAL
=================================
Assessment  1       5         6
Spec        3       2         5
Res         3       0         3
Total       7       7         14
```

The temp table has about 40 columns and I've been trying to insert them but honestly pretty lost as to how to do this effectively. I've attempted including the `INSERT` after the select clause but it doesn't return the new value.

```sql
INSERT INTO #tmpStatement
(
    Descr,
    ChgAmount,
    PayAmount,
    RunningTotal
)

VALUES
(  
    'Total', -- Descr - varchar(255)
    (SELECT SUM(ChgAmount) FROM #tmpStatement), -- CHG
    (SELECT SUM(PayAmount) FROM #tmpStatement), -- LATEFEE
    (SELECT SUM(RunningTotal) FROM #tmpStatement) -- TOTAL - money
)
```

The returned table however does not return the inserted record. Is this not possible? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP` constructs to achieve what you want

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(Descr) = 0 THEN Descr ELSE 'Total' END,
  SUM(ChgAmount),
  SUM(PayAmount),
  SUM(SUM(SomeCalculation)) OVER (ORDER BY Whatever)
FROM YourComplexQueryHere
GROUP BY (
    (Descr).
    ()
);
```

The `GROUPING` function tells you if the column has been aggregated or not.